# Matlab multiple image loading / processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to process 77 images on a single matlab script. I have to load these images and use several processing functions on each. The image names are not sequential. How can I do that without explicitly writing all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they all in the same directory ?

Comment: Yes all 77 are in the same directory.

Comment: OK, so why not just specify the directory and then iterate through all the files in the directory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `dir` to get a list of all the files and folders in the current folder you are in, for example

```
s=dir(fullfile(matlabroot, 'toolbox/matlab/audiovideo'))
```

returns the contents of the matlab/audiovideo folder, where `s.name` will contain the names of the files in that folder.

Another example:

```
 s=dir('*.mat')
```

will return to `s.name` all the file names in the current folder that are of type `.mat`

Now you can load these files in a loop:

```
 for n=1:numel(s)
     load(s(n).name);
     .... % do whatever
 end
```